# Keep User authenticated using Django Rest and Phonegap?

Tags: python, django, rest

I have read multiple tutorials on authentication but I am just as confused. I am trying to log a user in using an html form on the client device, which means I'm not using Django templates. Does it work like the following?

1. I send a post to rest backend with username, password combo
2. Django rest checks to see if valid user, and sends token back?
3. I save token in local storage, and send with every request of user?

What do I send from the front end to make this happen?

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you seeing? If you add more information it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: I'm asking what the pipeline for a service like this should be, tbh I do not no where to start, and was asking if this is right or there is a different way. I have only done authentication with django templates before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, send a post request to a RESTful backend with username and password combo
2. Django authenticates the username and password and logs the user in which sets a sessionid associated with the user which I believe you are referring to as a token.  This is done via the login() method. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login
3. Normally Django would set a sessionid as a coookie or session variable on the client's machine, but I'd imagine you could save it in local storage and then retrieve it each time and validate it's a valid sessionid on each request but it's easier to just let Django's middleware take care of everything by just using sessions.